# WordPress and phpMyAdmin

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

Website showing error:

> Error establishing a database connection

phpmyadmin not able to login:

> error:  #2002 - No such file or directory — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
>
> error: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
>
> error: Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

I have increased the size of the droplet still same error. Also restarted the server but that didn't work.

Comment: Have you entered the correct MySql login credentials into the 'wp-config.php' file?

Comment: open config.php and check there database, username and password correct or not? then check missing files from the structures.

Comment: The "No such file or directory" suggests to me that your MySQL installation is missing a file, either in a system or data directory. Have you any idea how that happened? It does not, in general, happen for no reason. I would be inclined to take a backup of your data directory and then reinstall MySQL. If the data is valuable, copy the data directory to a development machine, install the same version of MySQL, and make sure you can see the data.